# Spark wrongly casting integers as `struct<int:int,long:bigint>`

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue

In a spark job, I am using

```
.withColumn("year", year(to_timestamp(lit(col("timestamp")))))
```

This code used to work. But now I get the error :

```
"cannot resolve 'CAST(`timestamp` AS TIMESTAMP)' due to data type mismatch: cannot cast struct<int:int,long:bigint> to timestamp;"
```

I looks like spark is reading my timestamp column as a `struct<int:int,long:bigint>` instead of a `int`

**How can I prevent that ?**

Context the initial data is in jsonline. I read it using AWS GLUE `glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog`. In the GLUE catalog the timestamp column is typed `int`.

Comment: can you show the schema by `df.printSchema()`?

Comment: I found a way to force the type of timestamp before parsing it

Answer (score 3):

Finally I solved it this way :

```
GF_resolved = ResolveChoice.apply(
    frame=GF_raw,
    specs=[("timestamp", "cast:int")],
    transformation_ctx="resolve timestamp type",
)
```

ResolveChoice is method avaible on AWS Glue DynamicFrame

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that you cannot prevent it if creating a dynamic frame from catalog because, as the name suggests, the schema is dynamic. See this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56464035/how-to-specify-explicit-schema-aws-glue-pyspark-and-use-bookmarks) for more information.

Alternative approach that is a little more compact is...

```
gf_resolved = gf_raw.resolveChoice(specs = [('timestamp','cast:int')])
```

Official documentation for the resolve choice class can be found here.
[AWS Resolve Choice](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-transforms-ResolveChoice.html)